# Rails / Friendly_id. How to render 404 pages for old (ugly) URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url, friendly-id

I have installed the `friendly_id` gem for a new rails application in order to create pretty URLs for user profiles. And everything works fine, but I would like the old (ugly) URLs to return 404 pages, as it should be normal. At this point a user profile is available through both these URLs:

- ugly (old) URL: /profile/11
- pretty URL: /profile/jon-smith

The routes rule I'm using:

```
get 'profile/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

And strangely I couldn't find anything online that could help me with this issue, so any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Good to see you fixed it!

I was going to suggest something similar; since I'm on here, I might as well write that you could also achieve the same functionality with the [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) method:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find_by slug: params[:id]
   end
end
```

--

You could also make your routes a little clearer:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "profile", only: :show, as: :user
```

---

**Update**

If you wanted to use the `history` module, you'll have to use the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   friendly_id :username, use: [:finders, :slugged, :history]
end
```

... alternatively, you could also set the `history` module globally:

```
#config/initializers/friendly_id.rb
...
config.use :finders
config.use :history
config.use :slugged
```

This will basically copy your slugs to another table (by default called `friendly_id_slugs`), which `FriendlyID` will then look up against in the future:

```
#config/application.rb
FriendlyId::Slug.table_name = "slugs"
```

We used the following to change our table to just `slugs`:

[image]

--

An important note is that the `history` module only works with previous slugs.

Your original question was about using `ids`, not previous slugs. If you wanted to look up only previous slugs, yes, you'd use `User.friendly.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Ok, it seems I have hit a brick wall, because using friendly_id gem :history (to redirect past user pages to current ones) option I need to use it's friendly method like @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])

Comment: Adding friendly_id's :history option (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History), I need to use it's friendly method like @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id]) which redirects /profile/past-jon OR /profile/jons-id to /profile/jon. It probably first searches to find a matching slug, then a history slug or a matching record with the same id. So I'm figuring that modifying the gem's finder method that searches by id would be the cleanest route, but no idea what to change in here: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb

Comment: The question wasn't about past slugs, it was about showing a `404` if the user hit the `show` action with their `id`. That's the answer I gave; if you want past slugs, you will need to use the `history` module but you have to add an extra table (updated article)

Comment: True. I wanted `404` if the user hit the show action with their id. But adding the `history` module implied using `@user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])` which besides searching for past slugs also searches by user id, so it won't return a `404` page anymore for things like `/profile/1`. What I did eventually was modify gem's finder method to search only using friendly ids. I'll also update my answer with this. Thank you for the help, it led me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem man, thanks for the upvote if you gave it. The history module isn't necessary unless you're running something like a forum / blog, where the referenced URL is necessary for users to find bookmarked pages etc. Looking forward to seeing your update :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually found this thing to be working which doesn't appear in the current gem docs.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Will leave it here in case anybody else will need it

**Update**

Further, using the `history` module implies using `@user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])` which first searches for matches in the slug column, then for past slugs and in the end by `id`. Basically, using the `history` module redirects `/profile/past-friendly-id` AND `/profile/id` with `301` to `/profile/current-friendly-id` and I wanted for the `/profile/id` to just return a `404` code and page.

This let me to come up with a cleaner solution, change `gem`'s finder method to search only by friendy-id:

```
# /config/initializers/choose_name.rb
FriendlyId::FinderMethods.module_eval do
    def find(*args)
        id = args.first
        find_by_friendly_id(id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try do follow code snippet for yourself.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if params[:id].to_s.match(/^[0..9]+$/) && !User.friendly.exists?(params[:id])
      render "public/404.html", status: 404
    else
      @user = User.friendly.find params[:id]
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't cover it all, because on an open platform if someone chooses 34567 as their username, there will be a problem. I could further restrict usernames, but obviously I would prefer a cleaner solution, if there is one

Comment: ok. look. Actually, you want render 404 page for id params is format as number. But if you want username can be number format. you can look again my answer above.